# whether the Matrix is diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

Now let $V$ be the vector space of real polynomials in $x$ of degree at most $d$ where $d > 0$. Which of the following linear mappings of V into itself are diagonalizable?

$T_3\colon f(x) \mapsto f(x + 1)$

$ T_4\colon f(x) \mapsto f(−x).$

Yes.
I get the matrix for the mapping:
for $T_3$ and at most degree 2, the matrix is

$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 &1\\0 & 1 &2\\ 0& 0& 1\end{bmatrix}$

But how should I generalize it?

Comment: Also, what have you tried so far? Showing your work helps other users provide better and more accurate hints!

Comment: I agree that you can improve your question a lot. This is a nice exercise. Note that the matrix of $T_3$ with respect to the basis $\{1, x, x^2, \ldots x^d\}$ is triangular and its coefficients are the ones from [the Pascal triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not strictly necessary to find the matrices of these transformations, but doing so is a valid approach.  Here's an approach that doesn't require matrices:

**Hint:** Convince yourself that $1$ is the only possible eigenvalue of $T_3$ (that is: if $f$ is a polynomial $f(x+1) = \lambda f(x)$ for some $\lambda \neq 1$, then we must have $f = 0$).  If a diagonalizable transformation has $1$ as its only eigenvalue, which transformation must it be?

Alternatively, it suffices to note that the matrix of the transformation will always be upper triangular (but never diagonal) with $1$s on the diagonal.

**Hint:** Any polynomial can be broken up into an even part and odd part.  That is, any $f$ can be written as $f(x) = f_1(x) + f_2(x)$, where 
$$
f_1(-x) = f_1(x), \qquad f_2(-x) = -f_2(x)
$$
Recall that a transformation is diagonalizable if and only if every vector can be written as a linear combination of eigenvectors.

Alternatively, note that the matrix of the transformation is diagonal.

Comment: I understand that 1 is the only eigenvalue but how does it mean that there is not enough eigenvector

Comment: So T^3 can only be identity matrix if it is diagonalizable but it cannot map to f(x+1)

Comment: Can you explain T4 a bit more?

Comment: @stedmoaoa I think the hint is pretty clear. What have you tried?

Comment: How to use the fact that every vector should be a linear combination of eigenvectors and the polynomial can be broken up into even and odd? Thank you so much!

Comment: That didn't really answer my question. In any case, note that odd and even polynomials are eigenvectors of $T_4$.